# How to print questions and exercises in-place with xsim?

Tags: exercises, xsim

I'm working on a textbook, and I'm trying to use `xsim` for questions/exercises and their answers.

What I want to do is simple:

1. Place small question/exercise items throughout each chapter, approximately one per subsection, meaning anywhere from 10-20 per chapter.
2. Print the questions/exercises *in place*, i.e. if the end of section 12.3.1 has two questions, those questions *must* apper at the end of section 12.3.1.
3. Print the answer to all question/exercises in a special chapter at the end of the book.

EDIT: Here's mockup of what I want:

*IN MAIN MATTER:*

```
Chapter 14

14.1 Cats as pets

Text text text...

EXERCISES: 14.1
1. Draw a cat.
2. Bathe a cat.
3. Trace the history of cats through time.

Text text text...

14.2 Frogs as pets

Text text text...

EXERCISES: 14.2
1. Lick a frog.
2. Bathe a frog.
3. Feed a frog.

Text text text...

Chapter 21

21.1 The joys of fish

Text text text...

EXERCISES: 21.1
1. Catch a fish.
2. Draw a fish.

Text text text...
```

And in a single chapter at the end of the book:

```
SOLUTIONS TO EXERCISES

Chapter 14

14.1
1. Solution A
2. Solution B
3. Solution C

14.2
1. Solution X
2. Solution Y
3. Solution X


Chapter 15

15.1
1. Solution P
2. Solution Q
```

The problem is that in order place the answers in their own chapter at the end of the book, the questions must be placed in an `xsim` "collection" (`\collectexercises{foo}`...`\collectexercisesstop{foo}`), but putting them in a collection *prevents them from being printed in-place*. This makes sense if your goal is to print questions in a separate test document, but that is not what I need to do.

Any suggestions for doing what I want to do? Is xsim capable of this, or have I chosen the wrong tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need collections in order to achieve what you want. You can use `\ForEachUsedExerciseByType` to build your own lists. This command maps over all exercises that have been used in a document. Within the argument of the command you can refer to the exercise *type* with `#1` and to the exercise *ID* with `#2`. This allows you to check or call the properties of exercises, for example with `\ExercisePropertyGet{<type>}{<ID>}{<property>}`. (The available commands and properties are all listed in the manual.) With `\XSIMprint{exercise|solution}{<type>}{<ID>}` you can print the corresponding exercise or solution.

For the example below I define

```
\newcommand\printsectionexercises{%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}
      \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}
        \XSIMprint{exercise}{##1}{##2}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
```

which checks the section value against the current one and prints the corresponding exercise and

```
\renewcommand\printsolutions{%
  \def\currentchapter{}%
  \def\currentsection{}%
  \def\lastchapter{}%
  \def\lastsection{}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
    \let\lastsection\currentsection
    \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
    \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}}%
    \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
      \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter}}
    \fi
    \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
      \subsection*{Exercises \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section}}
    \fi
    \XSIMprint{solution}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
}
```

whih checks the chapter and section values and if they have changed insert a suiting heading and prints the solution.

Together with the package setup

```
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = number-only ,
  solution/template = number-only ,
  exercise/within = section ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  exercise/print = false
}
```

and the custom exercise template

```
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{number-only}{%
  \par\noindent
  \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
  \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
}{\par}
```

The exercises then are placed somewhere in a section and at the end of the section we use

```
\subsection*{Exercises \thesection}
\printsectionexercises
```

and later in the book

```
\chapter*{Solutions to the exercises}
\printsolutions
```

The complete example below gives

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{number-only}{%
  \par\noindent
  \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
  \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
}{\par}

\newcommand\printsectionexercises{%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}
      \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}
        \XSIMprint{exercise}{##1}{##2}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}

\renewcommand\printsolutions{%
  \def\currentchapter{}%
  \def\currentsection{}%
  \def\lastchapter{}%
  \def\lastsection{}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
    \let\lastsection\currentsection
    \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
    \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}}%
    \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
      \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter}}
    \fi
    \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
      \subsection*{Exercises \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section}}
    \fi
    \XSIMprint{solution}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = number-only ,
  solution/template = number-only ,
  exercise/within = section ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  exercise/print = false
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{13}
\chapter{}
\section{Cats as pets}
Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Draw a cat.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Drawing a cat.
\end{solution}

Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Bathe a cat.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Bathing a cat.
\end{solution}

Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Trace the history of cats through time.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Tracing the history of cats through time.
\end{solution}

\subsection*{Exercises \thesection}
\printsectionexercises

\section{Frogs as pets}
Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Lick a frog.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Licking a frog.
\end{solution}

Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Bathe a frog.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Bathing a frog.
\end{solution}

Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Feed a frog.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Feeding a frog.
\end{solution}

\subsection*{Exercises \thesection}
\printsectionexercises

\setcounter{chapter}{20}
\chapter{}

\section{The joys of fish}
Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Catch a fish.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Catching a fish.
\end{solution}

Text text text\dots
\begin{exercise}
  Draw a fish.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  Drawing a fish.
\end{solution}

\subsection*{Exercises \thesection}
\printsectionexercises

\chapter*{Solutions to the exercises}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is *very* close to what I'm trying to do. The only issue is how the solutions to the exercises in each chapter are organized and printed. In each chapter, I have 5-10 "bundles" of 3-5 exercises each, with each bundle at the end of a section. In the chapter with the solutions, what I'm going for (sorry if this wan't clear above) is to also organize the solutions by *chapter and then bundle*, e.g. `Solutions to exercises in Chapter 14` (this is a section) // `Exercise 14.1` (this is a subsection) // `Solution 1...` \n `Solution 2...` \n `Solution 3...` (ordinary text). Can this be done?

Comment: Regarding my comment above, doing this would seem to require organizing the "bundles" of questions into something higher-level, I suspect, to achieve this in the body text: `Exercises: 14.1` // `1. First exercise here.` // `2. Second exercise here.` // `3. Third exercise here.`.

Comment: @GilWilliams see my edited answer

Comment: Works perfectly! My heartfelt thanks.

Comment: @GilWilliams I'll add this to the examples in the manual for the next update of `xsim` :)