# Using 'xsim', how to print two ExerciseTypes and their solutions separately using custom templates

Tags: templates, exercises, xsim

I am trying to use two ExerciseTypes 'exercise' and 'question' using xsim. Both the ExerciseTypes will be used to display 'exercises' and 'questions' in different sections of a book and their answers separately at the end of the book. How to use ExerciseType 'exercise' for the desired purpose has been described by @cgnieder [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576998/how-to-print-questions-and-exercises-in-place-with-xsim?newreg=ab5e37a91fa54c5e93e60a4535115367). I have adopted the code as below:

```
    \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{exercise-temp}{%
    \par\noindent
    \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
}{\par}

\newcommand\printsectionexercises{%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
        \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}
        \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}
        \XSIMprint{exercise}{exercise}{##2}%
        \fi
        \fi
    }%
}

\newcommand\printexercisesolutions{%
    \def\currentchapter{}%
    \def\currentsection{}%
    \def\lastchapter{}%
    \def\lastsection{}%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
        \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
        \let\lastsection\currentsection
        \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
        \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{##2}{section-value}}%
        \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
        \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{##2}{chapter}}
        \fi
        \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
        \subsection*{Exercise \ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{##2}{section}}
        \fi
        \XSIMprint{solution}{exercise}{##2}%
    }%
}

\xsimsetup{
    exercise/template = exercise-temp ,
    solution/template = exercise-temp ,
    exercise/within = section ,
    exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
    exercise/print = false
}
```

To print an 'exercise', I use

```
\subsection*{Exercise \thesection}
\printsectionexercises
```

And to provide 'answer' to all the exercises at the end of the book, I use

```
\printexercisesolutions
```

The above codes give the desired result.

Next, I am trying to adopt the above code for the other ExerciseType 'question' as below:

```
    \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{question-temp}{%
    \par\noindent
    \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
}{\par}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
    exercise-env = question ,
    solution-env = answer ,
    exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{Question} ,
    exercises-name = \XSIMtranslate{Questions} ,
    solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answer} ,
    solutions-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answers} ,
    exercise-template = question-temp ,
    solution-template = question-temp ,
    exercise-heading = \subsection* ,
    solution-heading = \subsection*
}

\newcommand{\printsectionquestions}{%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
        \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}
        \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}
        \XSIMprint{question}{question}{##2}%
        \fi
        \fi
    }%
}

\newcommand{\printquestionsolutions}{%
    \def\currentchapter{}%
    \def\currentsection{}%
    \def\lastchapter{}%
    \def\lastsection{}%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
        \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
        \let\lastsection\currentsection
        \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
        \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{section-value}}%
        \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
        \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{chapter}}
        \fi
        \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
        \subsection*{Question \ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{section}}
        \fi
        \XSIMprint{answer}{question}{##2}%
    }%
}

\xsimsetup{
    exercise/template = question-temp ,
    solution/template = question-temp ,
    exercise/within = section ,
    exercise/the-counter = \arabic{question}. ,
    exercise/print = false
}
```

To print the 'question', I am using

```
\subsection*{Question \thesection}
\printsectionquestions
```

And to print the 'answer' to the questions at the end, I'm using

```
\printquestionsolutions
```

But the above codes for 'question' is not giving results similar to the corresponding code for 'exercise'.

**Question:** The result of the code for 'question' is different from that of the 'exercise' in the following two ways:

1. The heading of the question set (for example, 'Question 1.1' in the following screenshot) appears below the question set while it should appear above: [image]
2. The collection of answers at the end displays only the headings of the question sets (as in the following screenshot) but does not display the corresponding answers: [image]

I would be grateful if someone could help with the above problems. I am new to latex so please bear with me.

The complete code for ExerciseType 'Question' is as below:

```
    \documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{book}
    
    \usepackage{xsim}
    
    %%For 'Questions'%%
    
    \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{question-temp}{%
        \par\noindent
        \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
    }{\par}
    
    \DeclareExerciseType{question}{
        exercise-env = question ,
        solution-env = answer ,
        exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{Question} ,
        exercises-name = \XSIMtranslate{Questions} ,
        solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answer} ,
        solutions-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answers} ,
        exercise-template = question-temp ,
        solution-template = question-temp ,
        exercise-heading = \subsection* ,
        solution-heading = \subsection*
    }
    
    \newcommand{\printsectionquestions}{%
        \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
            \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}
            \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}
            \XSIMprint{question}{question}{##2}%
            \fi
            \fi
        }%
    }
    
    \newcommand{\printquestionsolutions}{%
        \def\currentchapter{}%
        \def\currentsection{}%
        \def\lastchapter{}%
        \def\lastsection{}%
        \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
            \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
            \let\lastsection\currentsection
            \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
            \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{section-value}}%
            \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
            \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{chapter}}
            \fi
            \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
            \subsection*{Question \ExercisePropertyGet{question}{##2}{section}}
            \fi
            \XSIMprint{answer}{question}{##2}%
        }%
    }
    
    \xsimsetup{
        exercise/template = question-temp ,
        solution/template = question-temp ,
        exercise/within = section ,
        exercise/the-counter = \arabic{question}. ,
        exercise/print = false
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{Chapter on Cat}
    
    \section{Cat-1}
    
    SOME TEXT...
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 1 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 1 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
    \end{answer}
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 2 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 2 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
    \end{answer}
    
    \subsection*{Question \thesection}
        \printsectionquestions
    
    \section{Cat-2}
    
    SOME TEXT...
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 1 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 1 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
    \end{answer}
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 2 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 2 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
    \end{answer}
    
    \subsection*{Question \thesection}
    \printsectionquestions
    
    \chapter{Chapter on Dog}
    
    \section{Dog-1}
    
    SOME TEXT...
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 1 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 1 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
    \end{answer}
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 2 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 2 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
    \end{answer}
    
    \subsection*{Question \thesection}
    \printsectionquestions
    
    \section{Dog-2}
    
    SOME TEXT...
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 1 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 1 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
    \end{answer}
    
    \begin{question}
        Question 2 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
    \end{question}
    \begin{answer}
        Answer of Question 2 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
    \end{answer}
    
    \subsection*{Question \thesection}
    \printsectionquestions
    
    \chapter*{\underline{Answers to Questions}}
    
    \printquestionsolutions
    
    \end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
Finally, I want something like the following using 'exercise' and 'question' in the same file:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This is a good question. I hope it gets a similarly good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the configurations that `xsim` provides may be puzzling.

**First**, options like `exercise/print` used in `\xsimsetup{exercise/print=false}` are per-exercise-type. That means, the general form of `exercise/print` is `<env name>/print`. So, to set for exercise type `question`, you need to set

```tex
\xsimsetup{
    question/template = question-temp ,
    answer/template = question-temp ,
    question/within = section ,
    question/the-counter = \arabic{question}. ,
    question/print = false
}
```

This explains Question 1

> 1. The heading of the question set (for example, 'Question 1.1' in the following screenshot) appears below the question set while it should appear above:

because with original setting `\xsimsetup{exercise/print=false}`, only exercises of type `exercise` are not printed, exercises of (new) type `problem` are still printed, by default. See also package manual (v0.21, 2022/02/12),

> 8.2. Environment Options & Hooks
>
> For each exercise type there are the following options for both environments, the environments’ names are the module names for the options (here using the “exercise” type):

Therefore what actually happened for Question 1 is, `problem` environments are printed immediately, and `\printsectionquestions` prints nothing.

**Even more puzzling**, the first mandatory argument of `\XSIMprint` must be one of "exercise" or "solution". Thus `\XSIMprint{answer}{question}{##2}` won't print anything, without any error thrown.

This explains Question 2.

**Full and updated example**

```tex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{book}

\usepackage{xsim}

%%For 'Questions'%%

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{question-temp}{%
    \par\noindent
    \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
}{\par}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
    exercise-env = question ,
    solution-env = answer ,
    exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{Question} ,
    exercises-name = \XSIMtranslate{Questions} ,
    solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answer} ,
    solutions-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answers} ,
    exercise-template = question-temp ,
    solution-template = question-temp ,
    exercise-heading = \subsection* ,
    solution-heading = \subsection*
}

\newcommand{\printsectionquestions}{%
  % ##1 type, ##2 id, ...
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \ifstrequal{question}{##1}{%
        \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}\relax
          \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}\relax
              \XSIMprint{exercise}{##1}{##2}%
          \fi
        \fi
    }{}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\printquestionsolutions}{%
    \def\currentchapter{}%
    \def\currentsection{}%
    \def\lastchapter{}%
    \def\lastsection{}%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
        \ifstrequal{question}{##1}{%
            \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
            \let\lastsection\currentsection
            \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
            \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}}%
            \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
                \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter}}
            \fi
            \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
                \subsection*{Question \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section}}
            \fi
            \XSIMprint{solution}{##1}{##2}%
        }{}%
    }%
}

\xsimsetup{
    question/template = question-temp ,
    answer/template = question-temp ,
    question/within = section ,
    question/the-counter = \arabic{question}. ,
    question/print = false
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter on Cat}

\section{Cat-1}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 1 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 1 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{answer}

MORE TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 2 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 2 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{answer}

\subsection*{Question \thesection}
    \printsectionquestions

\section{Cat-2}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 1 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 1 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{answer}

MORE TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 2 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 2 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{answer}

\subsection*{Question \thesection}
\printsectionquestions

\chapter{Chapter on Dog}

\section{Dog-1}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 1 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 1 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{answer}

\begin{question}
    Question 2 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 2 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{answer}

\subsection*{Question \thesection}
\printsectionquestions

\section{Dog-2}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 1 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 1 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{answer}

\begin{question}
    Question 2 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 2 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{answer}

\subsection*{Question \thesection}
\printsectionquestions

\chapter*{\underline{Answers to Questions}}

\printquestionsolutions

\end{document}
```

| Chapter on Cat | Chapter on Dog | Answers to Questions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Chapter on Cat] | [image: Chapter on Dog] | [image: Answers to Questions] |

#### Update: using two exercise types at the same

Apart from the generalization `\printSectionExerEnvsOfType` and `\printSoluEnvsOfType`, also note the `\def\lastsection{}` added inside `\ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else...\fi`, in `\printSoluEnvsOfType`, the generalized form of the `\printquestionsolutions` in my previous example.

```tex
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{book}

\usepackage{xsim}

%%For 'Questions'%%

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{question-temp}{%
    \par\noindent
    \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
}{\par}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
    exercise-env = question ,
    solution-env = answer ,
    exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{Question} ,
    exercises-name = \XSIMtranslate{Questions} ,
    solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answer} ,
    solutions-name = \XSIMtranslate{Answers} ,
    exercise-template = question-temp ,
    solution-template = question-temp ,
    exercise-heading = \subsection* ,
    solution-heading = \subsection*
}

\newcommand{\printSectionExerEnvsOfType}[1]{%
  % ##1 type, ##2 id, ...
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{##1}{%
        \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}\relax
          \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}\relax
%              \texttt{<##1><##2>}\par
              \XSIMprint{exercise}{##1}{##2}%
          \fi
        \fi
    }{}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\printsectionexercises}{%
  \printSectionExerEnvsOfType{exercise}%
}

\newcommand{\printsectionquestions}{%
  \printSectionExerEnvsOfType{question}%
}

\newcommand{\printSoluEnvsOfType}[1]{%
    \def\currentchapter{}%
    \def\currentsection{}%
    \def\lastchapter{}%
    \def\lastsection{}%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{##1}{%
            \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
            \let\lastsection\currentsection
            \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
            \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}}%
            \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
                \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter}}
                \def\lastsection{}%
            \fi
            \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
                \subsection*{Question \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section}}
            \fi
            \XSIMprint{solution}{##1}{##2}%
        }{}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\printexercisesolutions}{%
  \printSoluEnvsOfType{exercise}%
}

\newcommand{\printquestionsolutions}{%
  \printSoluEnvsOfType{question}%
}

\xsimsetup{
    % for exercise type 'exercise'
    exercise/template = question-temp ,
    solution/template = question-temp ,
    exercise/within = section ,
    exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
    exercise/print = false,
    % for exercise type 'question'
    question/within = section ,
    question/the-counter = \arabic{question}. ,
    question/print = false,
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter on Cat}

\section{Cat-1}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{exercise}
    Exercise 1 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution of Exercise 1 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{solution}

MORE TEXT...

\begin{exercise}
    Exercise 2 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution of Exercise 2 in Section 1.1 in Chapter 1
\end{solution}

\subsection*{Exercise \thesection}
\printsectionexercises

\section{Cat-2}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 1 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 1 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{answer}

MORE TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 2 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 2 in Section 1.2 in Chapter 1
\end{answer}

\subsection*{Question \thesection}
\printsectionquestions

\chapter{Chapter on Dog}

\section{Dog-1}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{exercise}
    Exercise 1 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution of Exercise 1 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
    Exercise 2 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution of Exercise 2 in Section 2.1 in Chapter 2
\end{solution}

\subsection*{Exercise \thesection}
\printsectionexercises

\section{Dog-2}

SOME TEXT...

\begin{question}
    Question 1 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 1 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{answer}

\begin{question}
    Question 2 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    Answer of Question 2 in Section 2.2 in Chapter 2
\end{answer}

\subsection*{Question \thesection}
\printsectionquestions

\chapter*{\underline{Solutions to Exercises}}
\printexercisesolutions

\chapter*{\underline{Solutions to Questions}}
\printquestionsolutions

\end{document}
```

| Chap 1 | Chap 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Chap 1] | [image: Chap 2] |

| Solutions to Exercises | Solutions to Questions |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Solutions to exercises] | [image: Solutions to questions] |

**Attempt**: Quicker `\printSectionExerEnvsOfType` and `\printSoluEnvsOfType`.

The new loop macro `\ForEachUsedExerciseByIDOfType{<type>}{<loop body>}` is quicker than both `\ForEachUsedExerciseByID{<loop body>}` and `\ForEachUsedExerciseByType{<loop body>}` because the new one won't loop through the internal list of (all declared) exercise types.

```tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1: type, #2: loop body
\NewDocumentCommand \ForEachUsedExerciseByIDOfType {m +m}
  {
    \tl_set_eq:NN \XSIMtmp \ExerciseType
    \xsim_foreach_exercise_id_of_type:nnn {used} {#1} {#2}
    \tl_set_eq:NN \ExerciseType \XSIMtmp
    \tl_clear:N \XSIMtmp
  }

\xsim_verbose:n
  { Defining~ loop~ macro~ \xsim_foreach_exercise_id_of_type:nnn } 
% #1: boolean property, #2: type, #3: loop body
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xsim_foreach_exercise_id_of_type:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \cs_set:cn {__xsim_loop_item:nnnnnn} {#3}
    \xsim_foreach_exercise_id:n
      {
        % type, id, boolean property (i.e., used, printed)
        \__xsim_deliver_exercise_details:nnn {#2} {##1} {#1}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\printSectionExerEnvsOfType}[1]{%
  % ##1 type, ##2 id, ...
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByIDOfType{#1}{%
    \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}=\value{chapter}\relax
      \ifnum\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}=\value{section}\relax
        \XSIMprint{exercise}{##1}{##2}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}

\newcommand{\printSoluEnvsOfType}[1]{%
  \def\currentchapter{}%
  \def\currentsection{}%
  \def\lastchapter{}%
  \def\lastsection{}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByIDOfType{#1}{%
    \let\lastchapter\currentchapter
    \let\lastsection\currentsection
    \edef\currentchapter{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter-value}}%
    \edef\currentsection{\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}}%
    \ifx\lastchapter\currentchapter\else
      \section*{Chapter \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{chapter}}
      \def\lastsection{}%
    \fi
    \ifx\lastsection\currentsection\else
      \subsection*{Question \ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section}}
    \fi
    \XSIMprint{solution}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It works perfectly but when I combine this code with that of the ExerciseType 'exercise' and use both 'exercise' and 'question' in the same file, it does not work. Can you please help me combine both the codes in the same file?

Comment: @Aarone In both `\printsectionquestions` and `\printquestionsolutions`, I used `\ifstrequal{question}{##1}{<true code>}{<false code>}` to filter out exercises and solutions belonging to non-question type(s). You can alter these places to achieve what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to do it. I'm a beginner and don't quite get the code. Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: @Aarone Suppose your document uses 'exercise' and 'question' exercise type, how do you want `\printsectionquestions` to print them? Like `\printsolutions` that "prints the solutions of all used exercises of all types ordered by type", or like `\printallsolutions` that "prints the solutions of all used exercises of all types ordered by appearance in the document"?

Comment: Actually, I don't want behaviours of 'exercise' and 'question' to change when they are used in the same doc. Currently, 'exercise' prints exercises at section ends (if given) and 'solution' of all the exercises in a chapter dedicated for them where they get printed section wise in order of appearance. The code which you have provided behaves similarly -  'question' prints questions at section ends (if given) and 'answer' of all the questions in a chapter dedicated for them where they get printed section wise in order of appearance. I want them act same even when they are used in same document.

Comment: @Aarone Can you provide an example to show how do you "want them act same even when they are used in same document"?

Comment: Please see the edit. I've added a picutre to show how the final pdf should look.

Comment: @Aarone Seems a typo in the picture: under "Solutions to Questions" - "Chapter 2", the "Exercise 2.2" should be "Question 2.2".

Comment: Yes, you are right. Under 'Solutions to the Questions', Exercise 2.2 should be Question 2.2. (In fact, 'Solutions to the Questions' itself should be 'Answers to the Questions'.). I'll change the picture.

Comment: @Aarone See the new example in my answer.

Comment: I am very thankful for your continuous effort to help me out, but there is still a bad news. Somehow, the final code you have provided does not compile in my computer. It gives following 4 errors. 1. 'Undefined control sequence. \printsectionexercises' 2. 'Undefined control sequence. \printsectionquestions' 3. 'Undefined control sequence. \printsectionexercises' 4. 'Undefined control sequence. \printsectionquestions'.

Comment: @Aarone Really? For example `\printsectionexercises` is defined by `\newcommand{\printsectionexercises}{%
  \printSectionExerEnvsOfType{exercise}%
}`. Try this way: copy the whole second example in my answer, paste it in a new tex file, then compile.

Comment: Ahh, I got it. The source of the problem is the TexLive version (TeX Live 2019) I am using.  When I checked your code with TexLive 2023 on overleaf, it worked perfectly. Guess, I've to, at first, update my TexLive to current version. :) Thanks a bunch for your persistent help!

Comment: @Aarone I just checked the second example with TeX Live 2019 on overleaf. What's really undefined is `\ForEachUsedExerciseByOrder`, which was added in [`xsim` v0.21 2022/02/12](https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/blob/06e3dba43b96ed493968ddd54add9fc8a1d9a264/HISTORY#L201). You can safely replace it with the previous `\ForEachUsedExerciseByType`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I, however, saw your comment only after updating my TexLive. :)